# Can plot_models be used with type="pred"?

Tags: r, sjplot

I tried to use the following code to produce figures depicting the predicted values for specific variables. However, I get the error:

```
Error in (show.zeroinf && minfo$is_zero_inflated) || minfo$is_dispersion : 
  invalid 'y' type in 'x || y'
```

Can someone explain me this error message? Is it not possible to specific the type="pred with plot_models? With only model (plot_model) it works...

Thanks!

```
data(efc)

fit1 <- lm(barthtot ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)
fit2 <- lm(neg_c_7 ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)
fit3 <- lm(tot_sc_e ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)

plot_models(
  fit1, fit2, fit3,
  type="pred",
  rm.terms = c(
    "c12hour", "c161sex", "c172code"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `plot_model` with `type = "pred"` instead of `plot_models`. Probably you want to have your features like factors like this (Here is only the output of first model):

```r
library(sjPlot)
#> #refugeeswelcome
library(sjmisc)
data(efc)

efc <- to_factor(efc, c161sex, e42dep, c172code)

fit1 <- lm(barthtot ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)
fit2 <- lm(neg_c_7 ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)
fit3 <- lm(tot_sc_e ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)

lapply(list(fit1, fit2, fit3), \(x) plot_model(x, type = "pred"))
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$c160age
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[1]]$c12hour
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[1]]$c161sex
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[1]]$c172code
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>